# @import less throwing ModuleBuildError in new version 3.11.0

Tags: less

Getting build error when Use @import (less) to treat imported files as Less as below.
app.less file

```
 @import (less) url('../node_modules/c3/c3.css');

**error** 

Module build failed (from E:/ATMCodeBase/microapps/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from E:/ATMCodeBase/microapps/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


    }
    @import (less) url('../node_modules/c3/c3.css');
  ^
Can't resolve '../node_modules/c3/c3.css.less' in 'E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\apps\chart-std\src'
      in E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\apps\chart-std\src\app.less (line 17, column 4)
    at runLoaders (E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20)
    at E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (E:\ATMCodeBase\microapps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ ./apps/chart-std/src/app.js 8:0-20
 @ ./src/loader/src/MicroappInstaller.js
 @ ./src/loader/src/MicroappLoader.js
 @ ./src/loader/index.js
```

--- if I remove (less) build is successful. In the new version we don't need to mention (less)?

Comment: If the import worked when you removed (less) then the answer is obvious. I have never used any version of LESS which required (less) when importing